# history.length adjustment

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to adjust the `history.length` value, for instance reducing it by one? For example:

```
history.length = history.length - 1;
```

Comment: Why would you want that? If I visit a random website and it clears the back/forward cache then I would not be very amused.

Comment: @Rory, You can try popstate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `length` is read-only, as described at the MDN `window.history` page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.history